# How to fade out my div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadeout

i have my div here

```
<div id="myBox" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
```

i used this sample of code and it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<script type=text/javascript>
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#myBox').fadeOut('fast');
}, 10000); //after 10 seconds 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works: (reduced to 1s)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myBox" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  i used this sample of code and it doesn't work. Any suggestions?
</div>
<script type=text/javascript>
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myBox').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 1000); //after 10 seconds
</script>
```

Did you include JQuery? Please show us the complete code if there is an error somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, a dumb mistake of mine ;)

Answer (score 1):

here is  a css method since this question is tag under css

```css
#myBox {
  opacity:1;
 animation-name:fadeout;
 animation-duration:1s;
 animation-delay:10s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 }
@keyframes fadeout {
from {
 opacity:1;
}
to {
 opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="myBox" style="position: absolute; top: 100px; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
Hello world
</div>
```

Comment: remember to put your prefixes for web browsers

Comment: Thank you too, repzero. This way seems acceptable to me :D

Comment: welcome Salmon Player :D

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely consider using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

It let's you use some *awesome* css animation *extremely* easily, and also gives you cross-browser compatibility!

Comment: many thanks for helping and letting me know for this feature.. i'll look it up closely